# Is the Component Manager in Magento 2 A Real Thing, or a Tech Demo?

Tags: magento2, component-manager

The Magento 2 dev docs make reference to a [Component Manager](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/prereq_updater.html) -- but it's pretty confusing what the component manager is supposed to be.  Is this a tech demo, or is this something that end-users are actually supposed to use?  If the later, how?

The [installation instructions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/prereq_updater.html) are a little bizarre -- they recommend you clone a GitHub repository and then copy part of that repository into your Magento installation.  This GitHub repository is also bizarre in that is has a root level `composer.json` that includes the meta package (good), but then in the `update` folder where the application lives there's a **second** composer.json, and a committed `vendor` source tree (weird).

As an "outside the company" Magento 2 developer, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with this.  Is this a tech demo?  Something that ships with some version of Magento 2 (EE? The downloadable package? Something else?) and provided so developers can have a version to test against?

Is there documentation on how to use the component manager?

What the component manager actually doing behind the scenes?

Is this something that's marketplace related?

Specifics are great, but even a general overview from someone who's been paying more attention to this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Component Manager is, indeed, a real thing, and the system that implements Magento Marketplace's GUI for managing packages.  There's [an open GitHub issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4159) regarding some of the confusion around how to install Magento.

Answer (score 1):

As the topic you referenced notes, cloning the updater is required only if you also cloned the Magento 2 GitHub for the code; otherwise, in a `.zip` or `composer create-project` installation, you don't have to do anything to get the updater.

The Component Manager updates components. The System Upgrade utility upgrades the Magento 2 software.

Currently, you might not be able to use the Component Manager because Magento Marketplace isn't live yet. You can use System Upgrade today though.

Comment: Is that accurate?  I've installed Magento via the meta-package/create-project method and I don't see anything that looks like a component manager in my admin, and the update URL returns a 404.

Comment: Component Manager is basically a replacement for the Magento Connect Manager. You'll see it in the Admin in System > Web Setup Wizard.

The updater is used by the Component Manager and System Upgrade to run the composer commands using a [cron job](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_cron.html).

Comment: Just in addition to what Steve explained, Web Setup Wizard (which Component Manager is part of) is an alternative to Composer CLI for managing packages. It's supposed to be used by users who don't have access to console or prefer Web UI over CLI. Also Web Setup Wizard has functionality specific to Magento (e.g., it displays type of package - module, theme, etc.) or is limited in some areas (e.g., it works with Magento Marketplace only, so it's not so general as Composer).